# How to remove ellipsized property of TextView from code?

Tags: android, textview

I set my textView to be ellipsezed in xml. Now on click I want it to expend and become not ellipsized.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Use [`setEllipsize()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setEllipsize(android.text.TextUtils.TruncateAt)) to change the ellipsize behavior of a `TextView`. For example, to turn off ellipsize use this:

```
myTextView.setEllipsize(null);
```